# Memory, CPU and IO of an Airflow task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-ecs, datadog

I am working on a problem to identify the intensive Airflow tasks which are using more memory or CPU or IO in an AWS ECS container. I can see the memory and CPU utilization overall from the ECS container. How do I go by specific process and task level? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ECS does not currently publish stats for individual tasks that are run via RunTask, only aggregate stats for tasks that are part of a service. I would recommend using a third party service like DataDog, or run your own Prometheus scraper. You can run these tools as a "DAEMON" type service in your cluster so that they run on each host in the cluster and watch the Docker stats for each individual Docker container that starts across the entire cluster.

Note that task level metrics are currently on the roadmap for ECS, so feel free to go leave your requirements and/or a +1 on this roadmap item in Github: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/70